# Min and Max button functionality in UITableVIew

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I want to do min/max (expand/collapse) button functionality.Please see bellow image for more information.Is anybody know how to develop this functionality.I have some examples but those are not like exactly what i want.Please help me to solve this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar kinda requirement few days back. I have done this using custom tableview cell.

Firstly, you have to pass the indexpath of each row to the cell. For this i have taken a property in custom tableview cell.
i.e, **@property(nonatomic,assign) NSIndexPath *indexPathOfCell;**

Now, you have to pass the indexpath of row in datasource method.

**- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;**

And you have to write a delegate method in custom tableviewcell so that when the user clicks on the min/max button you can reload that cell through this delegate call.

**-(void)reloadCellWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;**

You have to set the view controller as delegate for the custom tableview cell in which you are populating the table. In that class you have to maintain an NSMutableArray.

**NSMutableArray *selectedIndexPaths;**

When ever the **reloadCellWithIndexPath** gets called you can simply do same.

```
-(void)reloadCellWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
    if(![selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]){
        [selectedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    }else
        [selectedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

In **heightForRowAtIndexPath** method you can change the height for a particular row.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    BOOL cellModeChanged = NO;
    for (NSIndexPath *indexpath in selectedIndexPaths) {
        if(indexpath.section == indexPath.section && indexpath.row == indexPath.row)
            cellModeChanged = YES;
    }

    if(cellModeChanged)
        return 400.0;
    else
        return 100.0;
}
```

Comment: Can you send me an example.

Comment: @chaaruu: I have shared whatever i have implemented for this MIN/MAX functionality. In case of any query/concern please tell me which part you want a detail summary.